# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I downloaded the stanford corenlp  zip file from [https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/](http://this%20link) Then unzipped it and cd'ed into it. Now I tried running the following java file. `javac -cp "*"  SentimentAnalysis.java works` fine but `java SentimentAnalysis` throws error that Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
```

import java.util.*;

public class SentimentAnalysis {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // creates a StanfordCoreNLP object, with POS tagging, lemmatization, NER, parsing, and coreference resolution
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // read some text in the text variable
    String text = "Hello madam, this is a dam";

    // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

    // run all Annotators on this text
    pipeline.annotate(document);

}
```

}

The error is as follows

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP
    at SentimentAnalysis.main(SentimentAnalysis.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Have you researched what `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means?

Answer (score 0):

Verify jar using below step

- Download Java decomiler from http://jd.benow.ca/
- open jar via downloaded  decompiler
- Verify if required class  StanfordCoreNLP exist
- If class exist follow this post [how to run Java program including jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath)

Comment: Sentiment Analysis is the name of the Java file I am trying to run

Comment: Got  it does my suggestion helped?

Comment: Actually the issue is the stanford corenlp class is not being found in my own  function.

Comment: Nodeferror  means classes are present at compile time but missing at runtine

Comment: but I included the .jars file in my classpath using -cp "*"

Comment: Print your classpath and try giving fully qualified path of jar